Does the universe include everything, or merely everything that exists?
Does the universe include literally everything? Or merely everything that exists? I am asking this because I think that, to give an example, unicorns are not part of the universe, because they don't even exist. So, personally, I think the universe includes only that which exists. But what is the truth of the matter? Also, I would like to read what philosophers have written about this matter.

Philosophers can help with identifying the implications of a given definition and with crafting similar definitions which comport with common use with more useful or consistent implication. (Or philosophers can obfuscate, distort, and confuse meaning.) But they don't pick definitions except for their own use, like anybody else.

What makes you assume that the universe exists and is a meaningful concept? Does the set of all sets exist? Does even the set of all sets that are not elements of themselves exist? See this super upvoted answer by a forever-banned user.

Only the things that exist will fit in the universe. Of course, it is always expanding, so it's fine to think up new things.

@ScottRowe Even if the universe were not expanding: It changes permanently its state. Hence it seems appropriate to consider the universe to be a process.

Humor: Kiri-Kin-Tha's First Law of Metaphysics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S11lJMNE87U

@JoWehler A process serving what?

@8Mad0Manc8 We do not know any reason behind this process. One can even doubt that this kind of teleological question makes any sense here.

What do you mean by "unicorns do not exist"? They exist as the subject of our conversation, at least.

@enkryptor See Jo Wehler's answer.

@JoWehler A process is a means to an end which has a purpose. If you consider the universe as a process then that process must have a purpose.else you cannot define it as one. Sorry to get pedantic.

@8Mad0Manc8 I mean "Process = a sequence of events, states and actions". The definition is neutral concerning the question whether the process has a goal or not.

@JoWehler Doesn't action imply agency?

@8Mad0Manc8 The above process definition does not take action in the sense of agency. It is neutral also concerning the aspect whether the action is intended or not. E.g., Newton's "actio = reactio" is not meant in the sense of agency.

@JoWehler it's inclusive of agency and its a grey area in definition that's subject to question and use?

@Mad0Manc8 I use "agency= intended action".

@JoWehler +1 for slipperiness . and a process, is unintended action aswell as intended action. Never the twain shall meet?

Unicorn; a quadruped with a single horn projecting from its head

The universe is defined as all that exists. "Unicorn" is a fictitious animal. It is a name without a referent.
The name and the concept of a unicorn exist in the universe, but a corresponding animal does not exist in the universe.

I would say that the name and concept exists in people's minds. It's like: my car exists in the driveway, and I can take "a trip" in my car, but where does the trip exist?

@ScottRowe The trip – in case you actually made the trip and not only fantasized about it - is  a series of events within spacetime, the basic fabric of the universe.

@DikranMarsupial Apologize, I do not get your point.

@DikranMarsupial No problem. For the purpose of the OP’s question one may replace “universe” by “multiverse”. I think that affects only the wording. – More weight has the question how reliable are the current speculations about multiverses? I think, in theoretical physics and astrophysics the proof of the pudding is in the mathematical formalization of the physical idea: Which mathematical equations of the theory govern the mechanism of the phenomena?

The key to questions like this is to define what every word really means to you. Then you check the definitions against each other using some logic you are familiar and that you deem appropriate; and then you end up with some result like "true" or "false" or "maybe, maybe not" or "undecidable".
This is not sarcasm. Everyone of the words "universe", "everything", "exist" and "truth" have different definitions to different philosophical streams (and hey, while you're at it, you can add what definition of "time" you wish to use in this context). You have to first axiomatically pick these definitions and can then try to work out a result.
It is then also to be expected, and valid, to get different results depending on which definition you use.

Universe
Everything
Existence
Truth
Time

Just observe the length of the articles, and the multitude of streams, opinions and difficulties by judging the table of contents. You will not get a single, simple answer that is accepted by everyone.
Your very question showcases this:

unicorns are not part of the universe

This is a wild, wild, statement. It basically implies that you intend for "universe" to be equivalent to "our planet, as far as we know". Not only is it very possible for actual unicorns to exist on a different planet, they could even possibly exist on ours. White horses exists; unicorn horns exist; and there is zero reason to assume that it would be physically impossible for a horse with such a tusk to evolve.
I know how you meant your sentence, but this displays how difficult it is to talk about things that do not exist.
So heck, more reading:

Nothingness
Nonexistence

TLDR: if you want simple answers, or in some cases even answers at all, don't ask Philosophy. ;)

But first we have to decide what really means, here. I think that is the basic unsolved problem of Philosophy.

Right on, @ScottRowe! :D

Well, one could define universe as whatever he wants it to be, but when we talk about the universe we usually think of a physical universe, something like : all existing matter and space considered as a whole; the cosmos. In some definitions of universe, time exists too as part of the definition, but time here is basically related to spacetime geometry.
Starting from this, I suppose that your question is basically whether all mental states and/or imagimation/imaginary things, exist in this universe. Since mental states and imagimation, seem to be represented in a physical substrate (brain/nervous system), we could say that they are part (at least as an expression) of the universe, in accordance to @Jo Wehler's answer.
But I would like to make a differentiation between part, present and future. Past and future thoughts are not part of the universe per se: they do not exists in a
physical substrate, since no-one is thinking of them. Future-ones are potentially part of the universe and past-ones have been dissolved/incorporated  into the universe.
For example some chemical elements did not exists at the beginning of the universe: they were a potentiality. A chemical substance that has been dissolved into a solution, is not part of the universe per se, it is transformed into something else.

And since we can only discuss the past, we can't really say anything about the universe. Well, time to move on to other things.

@ScottRowe Oh, but we most certainly can discuss the future! For example, I am curious about your future answer ;-). We can also discuss the present, for example that I really like what I'm currently writing.

@ScottRowe Woops, now it is the past. Oh well ;-).

Somehow reminds me of a sentiment from Ernest Hemingway. But the idea that we can only talk about things that already happened comes from Robert M. Pirsig.

Nothing exists permanently. Things arise , change while persisting and vanish. Universe contains all those things which arise or had arisen in the past or will arise in the future. It includes both known and unknown. It also includes those things which are physical or in the mind like unicorns.

This is more like defining it as "the universe of discourse", a more mental definition.

Is inpermenence, permenent ?

@8Mad0Manc8 Yes. Except in the case of Nibbana which neither permanent nor impermanent.

@SacrificialEquation Yes, exhausting the logic?

I am surprised no one has mentioned Popper's and Penrose's 3 universes.
Popper's 3 Worlds
From wikipedia

World 1
The realm of states and processes as studied by the natural sciences. These include the states and processes that we seek to explain by physics and by chemistry, and also those states and processes that subsequently emerge with life and which we seek to explain by biology.
World 2
The realm of mental states and processes. These include sensations and thoughts, and include both conscious and unconscious mental states and processes. World 2 includes all animal as well as human mental experience. These mental states and processes only emerge as a product of biological activity by living organisms, and so only emerge subsequent to the emergence of living organisms within World 1.
World 3
The realm of the 'products of thought' when considered as objects in their own right. These products emerge from human "World 2" activity, but when considered as World 3 objects in their own right they have rebound effects on human World 2 thought processes. Through these rebound effects, World 3 'objects' may — via World 2-based human action on World 1 — have an indirect but powerful effect on World 1. In Popper's view, World 3 'objects' encompass a very wide range of entities, from scientific theories to works of art, from laws to institutions.

Penrose has his own take on the three worlds that I prefer to Popper's
Penrose's 3 Worlds

The Physical World
The Mental World
The Platonic Mathematical World


Clearly unicorns belong to 2 — they are imaginable — but not to 1 — they are not found in (physical) reality, though they may well be in a HarryPotterian one.
Title Question
So the answer to your title question is the counter question: Which universe are you asking about?

I would argue that the greek concept of universe encompasses platonic concepts, which could be said to exist in the same sense that meromorphic functions on the complex plane exist. But beyond that semantic mismatch, I would say that physical existence is not a universal or absolute property of physical histories, but philosophers and other animals within a given timeline of events would ascribe existence to themselves, but not to other unobserved timelines. Even if quantum mechanics wasn't a concept, philosophy could have simply postulated the notion of the multiverse as a broader type of parallel threads of existence.
So while in our timeline things like unicorns or dragons are concepts without observed instances, as some of the answers have asserted, I would argue that both on the grounds of being platonic notions that are not isolated, but have relationships with other platonic environments (always pertaining to different types of lore), but also on the grounds that there is nothing internally inconsistent within the notion of unicorns that make potential instances impossible. We simply live in a timeline where we happen to have nothing close to unicorns in our observable slice of time and space.
There is also a bit of confusion brought up by the term "multiverse", which is a clear oxymoron if we adhere to the original definition of universe. In this case, what we call "universes" next to the "multi" ought to be replaced by something akin to "geodesically complete spacetimes"

And in an alternative universe that does not contain unicorns but however does contain Luke skywalker and Han solo battling it out against the dark side of the force........:-)

There's two competing definitions of universe.
1 is everything that exists, period.
Another is, everything that exists in this same space-time as us.
The second definition is what many people mean when they talk about multiverses, and compare this universe to other universes.

It is well possible that the universe is literally infinite.1
In that case, literally everything and anything that is possible — however improbable — also exists, including things nobody ever thought of.
For example, it would be certain that an exact mirror of the Earth exists, existed or will exist, with a twin Peter Schneider typing these exact words.

1 We can see of it only what is within our light cone, which leads to statements like "the universe has a diameter of x light years". What is meant implicitly is the observable universe.

@MisterMiyagi A set that by definition does not include a certain element does not include it, infinite or not ;-). Even an infinite universe will not contain impossible things. It will include all possible things though, just like the set of natural numbers contains any number you care to mention that is larger than 0.

To paraphrase Sherlock Holmes, perhaps you would agree that: "Once one has eliminated the impossible, everything that is left, however improbable, must exist at some point"?

@MisterMiyagi We simply don't know whether the laws of nature as we know them are the same everywhere; they are also certainly not complete. But still, I would contend that the rules of existence are distinct from existence. It is a reasonable conjecture that things which are impossible according to our best knowledge do not exist. Of course we may err, and be proven wrong by the existence of something previously deemed impossible. That is how science works...

Following on from @AnoE, you also need to define the word "unicorn". During the renaissance, collectors would buy unicorn horns, which were, in fact, the tusks of narwhals. We could argue that the existence of unicorn horns implies the existence of unicorns (at least in the past), and then define unicorn to be another name for the original owner of a unicorn horn, i.e. a narwhal. Then we have a universe with unicorns.
Actually, the original unicorn may have been a misunderstood rhinoceros.

Cogito, we should abandon the old idea of divvying up the world into things that exist and things that don't exist.  Instead go Meinong's way and construct new categories for *"exists" e.g. exists in the mind (unicorns) and exists in the physical world etc.. I say "exists" because we may need a new word, like "subsists", to prevent confusion and also to make ontological discourses more readable. In this framework even nothing exists in some sense of the word. Bon voyage

When you say, "exists", it seems in your question that exist implies materially exists, as in, you can sense it with the 5 basic human senses. Hence you get answers that respond to material existence, like that by @JoWehler. But does existence not also include thoughts and ideas? Doesn't the idea of something, say for example a chair, inform what the material thing becomes?
You also separate everything from merely everything that exists. This implies that there are things that do not exist. This is a difficulty.
These questions (and they remain questions) are covered in some depth by Plato (see the Sophist and Theaetetus) and Aristotle (Metaphysics). I would shy away from secondary sources like those listed by @AnoE except as pathways to original sources. After the Greeks, reading Descartes brings you firmly into the modern world where materialism starts to rule supreme.
Be aware, however, that it is very difficult to remove all the layers of thought encrusting your own discovery. Behold all the previous answers as examples of this. Assumptions govern the responses, the largest perhaps being the modern assumption of existence being material (describable by mathematical physics alone). The truth may not be a simple statement or paragraph as you might hope but getting closer to it is nonetheless enlightening.

Universe = "Cosmos and all within".
QUESTION: Does the universe include everything, or merely everything that exists?
Do unicorns exist?  No.  Are unicorns "within the cosmos"?  No.  Does the universe include unicorns?  No.
Therefor...
ANSWER:  B-"merely" everything that exists
